# Show $\mathbb{E}X^2_n \rightarrow \mathbb{E}X^2$ in $L_2$ for set of rand variables $X_n \rightarrow X$ in $L_2$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Given sequence of random variables $X_n, n \in \mathbb{N}$ converges to X in $L_2(\Omega, \mathbb{P})$.

I need to show $\mathbb{E}X^2_n \rightarrow \mathbb{E}X^2$, where $\mathbb{E}$ is expected value of rand variable.

I tried to show it with fact that converging in $L_p$ follows converging for probability, which follows converging in distribution, i.e. $\mathbb{E}X_n \rightarrow \mathbb{E}X$ , but got nothing.

How can i solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $\Vert Z \Vert_2 := \mathbb{E}[Z^2]^{1/2}$ for a random variable $Z$. It is well known that $\Vert \cdot \Vert_2$ is a seminorm.

Note that

$$|\Vert X \Vert_2 - \Vert X_n \Vert _2 | \leq \Vert X- X_n\Vert_2 \stackrel{n \to \infty}\longrightarrow 0$$
by the reverse triangle inequality.

Thus $$\lim_n  \mathbb{E}[X_n^2]^{1/2}= \lim_n \Vert X_n \Vert_2 = \Vert X\Vert_2 = \mathbb{E}[X^2]^{1/2}$$
and thus evidently ($x \mapsto x^2$ is continuous)

$$\lim_n \mathbb{E}[X_n^2] = \mathbb{E}[X^2]$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

$$|\sqrt{\mathbb E[X_n]^2}-\sqrt{\mathbb E[X^2]}|\leq \sqrt{\mathbb E[|X_n-X|^2]}.$$

Comment: thanks, i got it. later i'll write complete answer

Comment: sorry, but now i want to prove your inequaltiy and can't do this, sinse $|\mathbb{E}X_n^2 - \mathbb{E}X^2| \le |\mathbb{E}X_n^2 | + | \mathbb{E}X^2|$, which is not less or equal to $\mathbb{E}|X_n - X|^2$. How can i show your inequality right?

Comment: My inequality was not completely correct. I edited my answer. And this comes from the fact that $\|X\|=\sqrt{\mathbb E[X^2]}$ is a norm (see minovski inequality). @Juicer